# Angular 14 cannot find Namespace 'NodeJS'

Tags: angular, typescript

can't initialize the interval variable

```
onStartGame(){
    this.interval = setInterval (() => {
        this.intervalFired.emit(this.lastno + 1);
        this.lastno++;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Angular program to see at console.log with start and stop clicks in Angular 14

Comment: This question is like completely incomprehensible to me. How is the title related to the content? What is your code supposed to do, why is it inside of a string, and what does any of it have to do with angular? Please take a moment to check out [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you probably have

```
interval?: NodeJS.Timeout
```

that is only while running in an NodeJs environment, when in browser that is not correct value anymore, so instead to maintain the type you can do this.

```
interval?: ReturnType<typeof setInterval>
```

this will work regardless if browser or nodejs